# OmnisharpSever not running on Atom

Tags: c#, .net, windows, atom-editor, omnisharp

Recently I installed Omnisharp on Atom editor. Unfortunately server is not working properly. No debug log or anything. Flame icon in the bottom left corner should turn green on server start. Not responding on toggle on/off. Also I already tried to reinstall omnisharp. Any ideas?

I'm using Windows 10 x64, .NET version - 4.6.1

[Printscreen of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCLHo.png)